# Django DRF TypeError: object is not iterable, how to approach this?

Tags: json, django, rest

Wondering what I'm doing wrong here. I'm running DRF with a React frontend. Trying to get one serializer to GET and POST a user's selected stations.

The AJAX POST works great, but the get on a page's initial load no longer works, and Django tells me: `TypeError: 'Station' object is not iterable.`

From reading around I'm vaguely aware that I shouldn't be declaring station with `many = True`, as this is causing the exception to be thrown. But I can't find any other way to get it working, it mangles the JSON POST request if I remove this option and stops the data validating.

The create is using custom code and is working fine.

Should I be trying to get this to work seamlessly or should I just hack it/make a different serializer to do the POST? Am I doing this in a logical way or have I got it all back-to-front?

**models.py**

```
class Station(models.Model):
    network = models.ForeignKey(Network, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='name', max_length=256)  # Field name made lowercase.
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    users = models.ManyToManyField('Account', through='UserStations')

    class Meta:
        managed = True

    def __str__(self):              
        return self.name

class UserStations(models.Model):

    station = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user  = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserStationListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = Station
    #        fields = ('id', 'name')
            fields = '__all__'

class UserStationsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        #many = kwargs.pop('many', True)
        print args

        super(UserStationsSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    station = UserStationListSerializer(many=True, required = False, read_only=False)
```

**views.py**

```
class UserStationList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):        
    queryset = UserStations.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserStationsSerializer
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from .views import StationList, AccountViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', AccountViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls


urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^$', views.StationList.as_view(), name='station-list'),
            url(r'user-station-list/', views.UserStationList.as_view(), name='user-station-list'),
                    url(r'^obtain-auth-token/$', obtain_auth_token),
                    url(r'station-list/', views.StationList.as_view(), name='user-station-list'),
]
```

Comment: Please, correct the indentation in your question. And when you say "POST" works great but not 'GET", which one? `user-station-list/` or `station-list/` ?

Comment: user-station-list with post. Station list just gives all of the station objects to the AJAX get request, I won't be using it for POST.